# Error 500 even with customErrors = off

Tags: asp.net

I've just uploaded an asp.net web project to a Fasthosts shared server (yes, I know!).  The site works fine on a different server, and builds successfully.  However, when I upload it (or even just the files in the App_Code folder) to the fasthosts server, I just get a flat error 500 message.

I've ensured that the web.config file includes: <customErrors mode="Off"/> but still nothing - just Error 500.

The Fasthosts server is running asp.net 3.5, which is what the web project is built to.

Can anyone suggest what might be wrong, or how I get more information as to the cause of the error?

Thanks all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have an error in the web.config revert to old web.config and see if that works.

Comment: Wouldn't an error in web.config be picked up when I build the project in Visual Studio though?  If I keep the old one there'll be error as it won't be able to connect to the database.

Comment: Apparently it's because Fasthosts doesn't support "handlers" in the web.config file.  Is this something which can be easily overcome?

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

In your web.config, remove it.